# How to solve $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}n^2\left(e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to solve this sequence limit: $$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}n^2\left(e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right) $$ but the only elementary way I found to solve it is to prove that $$ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n+\frac1n<e $$ for $ n > 3 $ and so $$ n^2\left(e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)>n^2\cdot\frac1n=\frac1n\to+\infty $$.

However proving the first inequality is not straightforward so I would like to know if there exist a more direct way to solve it.

Comment: Do you know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)=\frac{e}2$$

Comment: No, I have never seen this limit before. Any hint to prove it?

Comment: You can use L'Hôpital's rule. It is proven on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/FPHHv1UcrMA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the fact : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)=\frac{e}{2}$$

For the large $n$,

$$n^2\left(e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) \thicksim \frac{e}{2}n \longrightarrow\infty \quad \text{where} \quad n \longrightarrow\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=1/n$, then the limit becomes
$$L=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{e- (1+t)^{1/t}}{t^2}= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{e-e+et/2-11et^2/24}{t^2}=\infty $$
The Mclaurin expansion of $$(1+x)^{1/x}=e-ex/2+11ex^2/24+...$$